# ffmpeg keyframe extraction in Windows

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I had downloaded ffmpeg from this site : http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ffmpeg.

Can someone tell me how to extract keyframes from an flv, mp3 or mp4 video?

I tried this command that I found on the net :

```
ffmpeg -i Wildlife.wmv Desktop/img_%05d.jpeg
```

I got the error

> could not open file : Desktop/img_%05.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.FLV -vf "select=key" key_frame_%d.jpg
```

See the [ffmpeg documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), especially the video filter selection on [`select`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#select), for more information.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But Im getting an error : Access is denied. Whats the deal here?

Comment: That sounds like a permissions problem, not something specific to ffmpeg.  Do you have read access to the input movie and the directory you're writing the output to?  Also, there was a slight mistake in my command, so that might've been what caused the error.  Now fixed.

Comment: Alright, I tried the new command you posted(the new one just didn'y have the path I think), the permission error went away and I get this error : "Output file was empty nothing was encoded(check --s/-t/--frames parameters if used)".